# How to use a session variable to shorten parameter needs in my stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, session-variables, mariadb

I try to run as much logical business I can inside the database by creating stored procedures with the commands programmers usually do inside the application. So no more *'select * from table'* in my Java/PHP/etc code.

I create procedures like:

```
create procedure show_clients(user_account integer, client_type varchar)
begin
       select client_name from clients 
              where type = client_type and
                 user_owner = user_account; -- < this is done in every query
end
```

Off course all my queries will show only the rows that belong to the user that is operating that session. **So...**

**Is there a way that when the user makes his login into the app, my login procedure would save his `user_id` so in every procedure that needs to know the user, I put this session variable there, and that this approach would be safe so no other user in other session would see data that does not belong to them?**

Example:

```
create procedure login(_username, _password)
begin
    sessionUserId = 0;
    select user_id into sessionUserId from users 
        where login = _username and password = _password;
    if sessionUserId is null
        select sessionUserId;
        exit;
    else
        select * from users where id = sessionUserId;
        session_vars.this_session_id = sessionUserId; -- < more or less like this
end

create procedure new_show_clients(client_type varchar) -- < more light
begin
       select client_name from clients 
              where type = client_type and
                 user_owner = session_vars.this_session_id; -- < no need for a parameter!
end
```

**Note:** The session I am referring to is the web aaplication session in which the user logged in. I want to know if the MySQL calls will recognize this application's session and unify all the calls from it in one session in it's DBMS too.

Or.. will I have to create a MySQL user for each user of my application so MySQL store session variables for them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered that it is possible in this [site](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0201__Procedure-Function/LOCALSESSIONANDGLOBALVARIABLESINMYSQL.htm).

But I tested only on Delphi, where the session of the MySQL is kept alive until I disconnect the database connection component manually or by terminating the program.

We can use `set @varxyz = 123;` inside a stored procedure, which in where I can also use it's value to make a select. Unfortunately we can't use those session vars inside views or set them outside a procedure.

In PHP it is not possible to use this method because every call to server makes a new database connection, and so, I new session is made and we loose those vars we made in the session before that. I did not yet tested if we could save the database connection var `$connect` in a PHP session array. I do can, but will it maintain the same session in DB in the next `session_start()`?

I will test it and post the result here later.

Anyone can tell me if the Java way can keep a db session opened while the user make his page requisitions to the servlet?

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that is not a problem and creating new ones for yourself. Do not try to associate a database connection with a web user account or try to hold on to one connection -- you are asking for trouble and designing yourself into a corner full of limitations that you will not be able to scale out of without abandoning this strategy.  Pass the user identifier to each procedure.

Comment: There are also some inaccuracies here.  User-defined `@` variables are scoped to the database connection and can be freely used in and out of procedures (and keep their value until you clear then or disconnect).  They can't be used in views, directly, but they can be used in views if you wrap them in a stored function... but seriously, don't do what you are trying to do, because Heisenbugs and performance/scalability issues await you.  Also, no, you typically can't store a database connection in a web server session, and if would be a bad idea even if you could.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, but I will make a full study before I implement it, I am not crazy. I will use Delphi as Web Server, which will persist the session and the db connection as long as I tell them to.